# Opensource C/C++(MIngw) Firewall tools

Tags: mingw, firewall

There seems to be lack of opensource libraries/tool kits for building firewalls in Windows.Do you any others besides the WFP?I am also want it be compatible with Mingw.
And how would you programmaticly add a rules to it?

Comment: For a firewall to work in Windows, it needs to use the NDIS API. When you're using NDIS, it's less of a headache to just get the newest version of VS.

Comment: VS is Visual Studio, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but check out my project: [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html).  It is a library package for building user-mode firewalls (and related applications) in Windows.  It is also open source (LGPL) and MinGW-compatible, as you wanted.